# Dropdown Select Post Filter

Tags: posts, filters, dropdown

I would like to display the posts when I click on an item with the dropdown select

Currently, my select is OK, all my terms are displayed and all posts too.

I just want to know of it's possible to filter

This is my dropdown select :

```
<select name="soins-taxonomy">
    <option value="all">Tout afficher</option>

    <?php
    // Get the taxonomy's terms
    $terms = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'location',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'exclude' => 1
        )
    );

    // Check if any term exists
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
        // Run a loop and print them all
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <?php echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
        }
    } 
    ?>
</select>
```

And this is my Query to display posts :

```
<?php

$ourCurrentPage = get_query_var('paged');

$args = array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' =>  'etablissements',
    'taxonomy' => 'location',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $ourCurrentPage
);

// Custom query.
$query_loc = new WP_Query( $args );

// Check that we have query results.
if ( $query_loc->have_posts() ) {

    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $query_loc->have_posts() ) {

        $query_loc->the_post();?>


        <!-- START ARTICLE -->
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-30">
            <div class="single-etablissement">
                <p class="single-etablissement-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                <p><?php the_field('eta_adress'); ?></p>
                <p><?php the_field('eta_cp'); ?> - <?php the_field('eta_city'); ?></p>
                <p><?php the_field('eta_country'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END ARTICLE -->

<?php

    } // End while   

} // End if

else { echo '<p>Aucune actualité trouvée</p>'; } ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tax_query` for [Taxonomy Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) for your [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

```
$term_id = $_REQUEST ['soins-taxonomy'];  // or use $_POST or $_GET as the case may be

$args = array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' =>  'etablissements',


    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $term_id,
      ),


    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $ourCurrentPage
);
```

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $location = isset($_GET['location']) ? $_GET['location'] : '';?>

<form action="" method="GET" >
                <select name="location" id="location" onchange="submit();">
                <option value="" <?php echo ($location == 'location') ? ' selected="selected"' : 'location'; ?>>Show all</option>
                <?php 
                    $locations = get_categories('taxonomy=location&post_type=etablissements'); 
                    foreach ($locations as $location) : 
                    echo '<option value="'.$location->slug.'"';
                    echo ($location == ''.$location->slug.'') ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                    echo '>'.$location->slug.'</option>';
                    endforeach; 
                ?>
                </select>
</form>
$taxs = array();
 if( isset($_GET['location']) && '' != $_GET['location']) {
$taxs[] = array(
        'taxonomy' =>'location',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $location
        
);
}
$args['tax_query'] = $taxs;
```

may be it's help you :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).